# .Net Sockets - 10054 Error

Tags: .net, sockets, udp

We have a windows service that has been happily running in production for over a year. Just recently it has started giving trouble. I don't have any experience of socket programming but I've got to try and find the cause of the problem - great!

The service is installed on a central server. It "listens" for data coming from approximately 400 servers located in stores across the country.

On starting, the service gets a list of stores it needs to collect data from, along with the ipaddress of the store server. It then loops through the list and executes the following code:

```
IPEndPoint lep = new IPEndPoint(lipa.AddressList[lipa.AddressList.GetUpperBound(0)], (int)portNumber);
PosListener posListener = new PosListener(lep,this.pendingBacklog,storeTable,messageList);
```

The constructor for the PosListner is as follows:

```
internal PosListener(IPEndPoint lep, int pendingBacklog, Hashtable storeTable, ArrayList messageList) : base(lep.Address.AddressFamily,SocketType.Stream,ProtocolType.Tcp) 
{
   ITraceState trState = PosApplication.Trace.StartProc("PosListener");
   try 
   {         
       // Setup listener
       this.ngcIPAddress = lep.Address.ToString();
       this.ngcPort = lep.Port;
       this.storeTable = storeTable;
       this.storeLock = new ReaderWriterLock();
       this.messageList = messageList;
       this.messageLock = new ReaderWriterLock();
       this.handlerList = new ArrayList();
       this.handlerLock = new ReaderWriterLock();
       this.asyncCallback = new AsyncCallback(this.CallbackAccept);
       this.Bind(lep);
       this.Listen(pendingBacklog);
       // Start listening
       PosApplication.PosSocketsEventLog.WriteEntry("Starting Listener on NGC Port "+this.ngcIPAddress+":"+this.ngcPort);
       PosApplication.Trace.WriteDebug("Starting Listener on NGC Port "+this.ngcIPAddress+":"+this.ngcPort);

       this.BeginAccept(this.asyncCallback,null);
   } 
   catch (Exception e) 
   {
        ExceptionManager.Publish(e);
   } 
   finally 
   {
       trState.EndProc();
   }
}
```

My understanding is that the constructor registers the method CallbackAccept to be executed whenever traffic is found on the a socket that's being monitored.

This callback method is pasted below:

```
private void CallbackAccept(IAsyncResult ar) 
{
    ITraceState trState = PosApplication.Trace.StartProc("CallbackAccept");
    try 
    {
        // Get the socket that handles the client connection
        Socket connection = this.EndAccept(ar);

        // Start listening for the next client connection
        this.BeginAccept(this.asyncCallback,null);

        string storeIPAddress = ((IPEndPoint)connection.RemoteEndPoint).Address.ToString();
        int storePort = ((IPEndPoint)connection.RemoteEndPoint).Port;
        PosApplication.Trace.WriteDebug("Listener "+this.ngcIPAddress+":"+this.ngcPort+" received connection request from "+storeIPAddress+":"+storePort);            

        // Check the remote end point has a recognised Store IP Address
        this.storeLock.AcquireReaderLock(-1);
        bool isAcceptable;
        try 
        {
            isAcceptable = this.storeTable.Contains(storeIPAddress);
        } 
        finally 
        {
            this.storeLock.ReleaseReaderLock();
        }

        // Close connection and throw exception if the remote end point
        // does not have a recognised Store IP Address
        if (!isAcceptable) 
        {

            connection.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            connection.Close();

            CrmServiceException ce = new CrmServiceException(
              "Client",
              "ConfigurationError",
              "PosSocketsService.UnSupportedStoreIPAddress",
              PosApplication.Trace,
              this.ngcIPAddress,
              this.ngcPort.ToString(),
              storeIPAddress,
              storePort.ToString());
              throw ce;
        }

        // Setup a connection handler
        this.handlerLock.AcquireWriterLock(-1);
        try
        {       
            IPosHandler posHandler = PosApplication.ConstructIPosHandler(this,connection);
            this.handlerList.Add(posHandler);
        } 
        finally 
        {
            this.handlerLock.ReleaseWriterLock();
        }

    } 
    catch (ObjectDisposedException) 
    {
        // this object has been disposed by another thread
    } 
    catch (SocketException e) 
    {
        ExceptionManager.Publish(e);
        PosApplication.Trace.WriteDebug("Unexpected Socket Exception Closing Listener "+this.ngcIPAddress+":"+this.ngcPort);
        this.Dispose();
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        ExceptionManager.Publish(e);
    } 
    finally 
    {
        trState.EndProc();
    }
  }
```

The details of the exception are as follows:

> ---
>
> Exception Type:
>   System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
>
> ErrorCode: 10054
>
> Message: An existing connection was
>   forcibly closed by the remote host
>
> SocketErrorCode: ConnectionReset
>
> NativeErrorCode: 10054
>
> Data:
>   System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal
>
> TargetSite: System.Net.Sockets.Socket
>   EndAccept(Byte[] ByRef, Int32 ByRef,
>   System.IAsyncResult)
>
> HelpLink: NULL
>
> Source: System
>
> StackTrace Information
>
> ---
>
> at
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndAccept(Byte[]&
>   buffer, Int32& bytesTransferred,
>   IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>
> at
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndAccept(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)
>
> at
>   Fujitsu.eCrm.Seoul.PosSocketsService.PosListener.CallbackAccept(IAsyncResult
>   ar) in
>   C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\PosSocketsService\PosListener.cs:line
>   109

Line 109 is as follows:

```
Socket connection = this.EndAccept(ar);
```

The behaviour we're seeing is that the POSListners are all started when the service starts. Then after a short period each one is closed - with the the same 10054 exception being raised.

It seems that the listener is triggered by data appearing on the monitored port but when the callback method attempts to create a socket so that the data be read - windows is not able to establish the socket.

Could anyone please suggest what steps could be taken to try and isolate the root cause of the problem?

Comment: You could switch off all of the 400 machines and try one by one, you could also indent your code so that it formats properly - both huge undertakings, I know.

Comment: Sorry, he's right. The way you have your code formatted (and not formatted) right now has made your examples unreadable. Please fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This design looks very strange to me.  You are issuing 400 separate listens, afai can tell.  Typically sockets servers will issue one listen, and then distinguish between incoming client connections ("which server just connected?") using some identification data that is sent or the source IP.

I cannot see what is actually wrong here, but I question this design.  My guess would be resource limitations on the server, perhaps the server load profile has changed since the code was working.

Answer (score 5):

This happens because one of your clients is FORCIBLY (ungracefully if you like) disconnecting from your server.

To give an example, on a typical GUI there should be Connect/Disconnect buttons. However, if the user connects and shuts down the application abruptly the socket will not have time to terminate the connection with the server. This could happen when a firewall kicks-in or there are line-connection problems.

In any case, I recommend that you handle the SocketException with the specific error code by closing the socket yourself (the server-side) as well.

Comment: The question indicates that ALL the connections fail, not just one.

Comment: In this context "FORCIBLY" disconnecting means "does not send ACK"